# Add a color highlight to closed questions in the question lists

Tags: script, search, closing

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

Adds a color highlight to closed questions. Inspired on a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345322) asked by [Hakan Fıstık](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4390133/hakan-f%c4%b1st%c4%b1k)

[image: closed / duplicate / on hold higlighted in red]

### About

The script will highlight the close reason found at the end of a question title in red.

This might be efficient for users that either want to salvage potential value or users that scan the search results looking for questions to answer.
The script finds the question links in the question list pages and check if their title ends with duplicate, closed or on hold. The script then wraps that text in a SPAN element so it can get a different color by the provided styling.

#### License

CC0

#### Download

[Source](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/blob/master/christmasclosing.user.js)    [Install](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/raw/master/christmasclosing.user.js)

#### Platform

The script is tested in TamperMonkey on Chrome Windows 10. It should work on any decent script manager as long as it isn't GreaseMonkey.

### Contact

You can leave an answer here if you've found a bug or have a feature request. [Direct PR's](https://github.com/rschrieken/SmallButHandy/pulls) are welcome as well.

### Code

The script is 100% jQuery and there is still not enough of it in this script.

I did use a MutationObserver.

<sub>Originally posted on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/345330)</sub>

### Version history

| Version | Changes |
| --- | --- |
| 0.3 | initial version |
| 0.5 | moved to GitHub |
| 0.6 | Honored Stacks Design and uses .js-* classes now to hook-up functionality |